# python3.3+ how to define package-variables (__init__.py), without declaring package 'closed' via __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-import, python-3.3

I have two repos intending to define things in package `corp`, the namespace used for our company's code. python3.5:

- `<repoA>/corp/foo/bar`
- `<repoB>/corp/foo/zing/zam`

The issue is that in A there exists `<repoA>/corp/__init__.py` defining some code at package level.

This seens to mark 'closed' the `corp` package with respect to import resolution (and this seems correct per my understanding of the design in >= python3.3).  So code cannot `import corp.foo.zing` because it doesn't treat anything in `<repoB>/corp` as in package `corp` (`repoA` is before `repoB` in `PYTHONPATH`).

`<repoA>` is a long-standing central repo with functionality such as corp-security, dbo stuff, etc - for (Reasons) it's pretty 'legacy' and we can't add our code to it directly.  So we have our own repo B, and both `<repoA>` and `<repoB>` are on `PYTHONPATH` on systems that use B.

Is there a way to code things so that client code can remain identical

- calls eg `import corp ; print(corp.some_package_var)`

but code in `<repoB>/corp/foo/zing` can still be resolved via a normal `import corp.foo.zing` ?  (I *AM* able to change `repoA` if client code will see no difference.  It's not completely out of the question if client code would need to change, but it becomes *very* difficult given the wide internal uses without a robust release process)

Comment: Recommended reading: [namespace packaging](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/).

Comment: Thanks for the link; confirms my understanding of __init__.py presence breaking the package-split-across dirs.  Still have the OP, which is how to define variables at "package" scope, or at least to appear at package scope

Comment: I guess it's worth adding that a solution to this would possibly lead to the diamond problem, or (ok for my specific use with the existing corp repoA) have _just_ repoA define package-level variables for `corp`